# JQuery ajax() post throwing error with special character in data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, encoding, stringify

I'm hoping that someone could help me figure out what is going on with a .net core web-api application that I have been writing - I've spent a whole day attempting to debug this and it's driving me crazy.

The server application is written in c# using asp.net core 1.1 under VS 2017 RC. I have a controller for accepting a post which will return a simple object. For reference, the basic controller class looks like the following :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] websiteOrder myOrder)
    {
        return StatusCode(201, new ObjectResult( OrderRepos.Add(myOrder)));
    }
```

I am using a JQuery ajax() call at the client, as follows :

```
$.ajax({
        url: myURL+"prices",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data:JSON.stringify(myCart),
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
        ...
        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ...
        }
```

This work FINE most of the time. However I notice that certain orders were causing the ajax() call to error with a 400 Bad Response. On finally tracking this down it come down to the presence or not of a '£' (UK Pound) symbol within the MyCart data. If the £ is present then it errors. If I switch the £ for a $ sign then it works fine.

The 'stringified' JSON for the good and bad versions of data are as follows :

This works:

> [{\"sku\":\"WA01GMT\",\"num\":1,\"price\":\"$180.00\",\"desc\":\"Watch 01 - Gunmetal with tan strap\",\"cCode\":\"GB\"}]"

This doesn't work:

> [{\"sku\":\"WA01GMT\",\"num\":1,\"price\":\"£180.00\",\"desc\":\"Watch 01 - Gunmetal with tan strap\",\"cCode\":\"GB\"}]"

The only difference I can see is the £ character. I was under the impression that all ajax() calls were utf-8 by default. Am I missing something obvious around encoding or locale? I have considered (briefly) encodeURIComponent() etc. but this is POST rather than a GET and my understanding is that this should be encoded correctly by default?

BTW when the error occurs nothing is triggered at the server side as I have a breakpoint watching on the controller. The server and client are both running on the same local machine using IIS.

Any thoughts / guidance would be very gratefully received.

IMPORTANT EDIT :

I have done some further testing on this. I had assumed that the problem was with the ajax() call and encoding, not the server side. However I may have misled you with this - apologies.

On the server side there is a database record which is being looked up via a DbContext. This database is originally supplying the data that goes into the myCart object earlier in the process and then is being accessed again when this particular ajax() POST returns to the server. This field with the £ symbol is not an index or a {id} field within the controller however - purely ancillary data included in the POST.

Oddly, if the £ character is in the database, then the call errors, even if I edit it out manually on the client side before submitting the ajax POST :

```
myCart[0].price = "$180";
```

Basically, in summary, I now have a situation where the JSON string is identical in two scenarios (with the $ sign present) when the POST take place but in one case it errors and the other it doesn't. The difference being that a £ sign is present in the server SQL database record being accessed by the controller back at the server. As I mentioned earlier - none of the code within the controller or interface appears to be exercise with the error occurring somewhere earlier (any suggestions where this might be?)

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Prices")]
public class PricesController : Controller
{
    public IPrice PriceRepo { get; set; }

    public PricesController(IPrice _repo)
    {
        PriceRepo = _repo;
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] IEnumerable<ProductOrder> myCart) 
    {
        return StatusCode(201, new ObjectResult(PriceRepo.GetTotals(myCart)));
    }


    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetPrice")]
    public IActionResult GetById(string id, string cCode)
    {
        var item = PriceRepo.Find(id,cCode);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }
}
```

Sorry to mess you around on this - I will shift my investigations to the server database and encoding around that to see if I can find the problem so please don't worry about things not working in the ajax call - which doesn't appear to be the case.

I am new to .net core and fairly new to MVC, so there is probably something fairly basic going on around encoding within the database that may be causing the issue. Any additional thoughts would be welcome to point me in the right direction :-)

FINAL EDIT - then I'm giving up :-(

This appears to be a problem with the local MSSQLLocal Express database on my machine. When I publish this to Azure and use the Azure SQL database the problem goes away - it only happens when running locally.

I've tried changing the collation of the column in question to a Latin_100 collation, but that hasn't appeared to make any difference (bit of a stab in the dark anyway).

If anyone can explain to me why a £ sign in one of the fields in my local database sitting behind a web-api controller is causing a 400 error when calling the controller for that particular record I would love to know :-( and will be delighted to recommend the answer :-). For the time being I going to do what I do best and work around it as it appears to work OK in the production environment :-)

Thanks for your comments

Comment: The page on the server side, the one that is requested via ajax, should be specified for utf-8 too. If it were on php, with a header like: ``header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`` (just an example).

Comment: I remember having a similar problem using web2py and the issue was with the encoding. Try adding a <meta charset = "utf-8"> to the file referenced by myURL.

Comment: just as a side note , prices should not be strings from the database . They should be decimals .  Then you should use an enum for currency type and on the front end you could display the proper character in front of the price like the dollar sign

Comment: Scott, that's a fair comment in general. However in this specific case this is a formatted price string for display purposes and is being done for a reason to support some specific aspects related to multi currency that I'm working on. The price is also held in the Db as a value.